# Possible bug or feature change in TikZ library going from TeX Live 2018 to 2019?

Tags: tikz-pgf, texlive-2018, texlive-2019

Compiling the code below with LuaLaTeX with TeX Live 2018 gives me the desired result after three runs (to get the references correct).

Changing to TeX Live 2019, i get an error from PGF:

> (c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
>
> ! Package pgf Error: No shape named two is known.
>
> See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
>   Type  H   for immediate help.
>    ...
>
> l.18   \node[above=4mm of two]
>                                (minussigntext) {
>   ?

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,tikzmark}
% positioning used for above= and below=
% tikzmark used for subnode

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
  \node{$
    \subnode{sign1}{$\color{red}-$}
    3
    \mathbin{\subnode{minusoperator}{$\color{blue}-$}}
    \subnode{two}{$2$}
    =
    \subnode{sign2}{$\color{red}-$}
    5
  $};
  \node[above=4mm of two] (minussigntext) {
    \color{red}  Minus symbol as sign
  };
  \node[below=4mm of two] (minusoperatortext) {
    \color{blue} Minus symbol for subtraction
  };
  \draw [-] (minussigntext)     to [out=230,in= 90] (sign1);
  \draw [-] (minussigntext)     to [out=310,in= 90] (sign2);
  \draw [-] (minusoperatortext) to [out=110,in=270] (minusoperator);  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Desired result:

[image: desired result]

Comment: See https://github.com/loopspace/tikzmark/issues/8#

Answer (score 2):

Ulrike Fischer points in the right direction. This seems to be an issue with tikzmark v1.7. I tried compiling with this [this](https://github.com/loopspace/tikzmark/blob/86f4bd718573cf08ddbc9297a113e7bc9278d79c/tikzmark.dtx) commit from may 13 2019 in the github page for tikzmark, and it solved my problem. There was also some other syntax problems with my original code; below is a better version. I shouldn't have used $ inside the subnodes, because that exited mathmode. I expect the issue is going to be resolved in a newer version of tikzmark.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,tikzmark}
% positioning used for above= and below=
% tikzmark used for subnode

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
  \node (expression) {$
    \subnode{sign1}{\color{red}-}                     % -
    3                                                 % 3
    \mathbin{\subnode{minusoperator}{\color{blue}-}}  % -
    2                                                 % 2
    \mathrel{=}                                       % =
    \subnode{sign2}{\color{red}-}                     % -
    5                                                 % 5
  $};
  \node[above=4mm of expression] (minussigntext) {
    \color{red} Minus symbol as sign
  };
  \node[below=4mm of expression] (minusoperatortext) {
    \color{blue} Minus symbol for subtraction
  };
  \draw [-] (minussigntext)     to [out=230,in= 90] (sign1);
  \draw [-] (minussigntext)     to [out=310,in= 90] (sign2);
  \draw [-] (minusoperatortext) to [out=110,in=270] (minusoperator);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```